# Android SDK Manager Update - Eclipse Not generating activity_main, main.java, or correct manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, updates

I was prompted for an update on my android SDK manager this morning. Since then Ive tried to create some new projects in eclipse. For some reason my activity_main.xml is not being generated (its is checked during the create project steps), there is no default main.java, and my intents node under my manifest is not present. Although i've worked around this, it is a hassle. Does anyone know why this isnt working correctly ? 
Ive Tried:

1. creating another android application
2. a different computer 
   (which worked fine - received the update - and then started the same behavior)

The only guess I have is the versions of the SDK and Eclipse are out of sync somehow... 
The reason i think this is because after the SDK manager update it recommended that I update eclipse ( Help > Check For Updates ). Which ive done and restarted the ide to no avail.

[image: Android SDK Manager Version]
[image: Eclipse-Android Version]

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

click "Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

it's work for me

ref from :https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647

Answer (score 0):

Go to following: 
*'Help'->'Install New Software'* and type 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it.
It will update the ADT.

Even I had the same problem and my issue got resolved with it!!